# Drag and Drop в GridView

Tags: android, gridview

Необходимо менять объекты местами по сетке в `GridView`.
Как происходит перетаскивание понятно. А вот сама замена объекта на объект (view) не могу разобраться . 
Киньте годный пример или "на пальцах " объясните.

Comment: https://medium.com/@ipaulpro/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-b9456d2b1aaf#.5cw6qea5o